# What is Karna Guru?

Tags: guru

What is karna guru and Is it compulsory to take mantra from karna guru?

Comment: I know about many types of Gurus for eg- Tortoise Guru, Mirror Guru etc etc but i am not aware of Karna Guru. Are u spelling it correctly?

Comment: You belong to which state? And what their characteristics? I mean what exactly do they do?

Comment: @Rickross Karna Parampara is a term for oral tradition, so it's possible that a Karna Guru is just a general term for anyone who teaches through oral tradition.

Comment: Well all Gurus give mantras in the disciple's ear only. And ear=karna. So i can not figure out what's so special about these Gurus that they have got such names. I am not sure how to answer this. I have never encountered this term in any of the scriptures that i have read so far. @K.C.Polai Also if bounty expires what will happen? Will u not get the reputation back again?

Comment: @K.C.Polai hope you are not referring to KARNA PISHACHINI MANTRA

Answer (score 1):

Robert Svoboda, quoting Vimalananda (his Aghori mentor):

> Vitthala wanted to initiate him into the undifferentiated reality, by killing, butchering, and cooking: Sadguru, Karnaguru, and Upaguru. Have you ever heard of the Sadguru, Karnaguru, and Upaguru? The Sadguru kills the aspirant - separating him from his mundane existence. **The Karnaguru flays the carcass: the ego.** All the accretions of untold births, the false personality, is chopped into tiny pieces. When my Mahapurusha cut Haranath Thakur, my parents' guru, into tiny pieces and removed Sattva, Rajas, and Tamas from the pile of sixty-four, this is what He was doing. The Upaguru cooks the ego in the fire of Shakti, and the result is a tasty dish: an enlightened being. The best guru, of course, combines the Sadguru, Karnaguru, and Upaguru into one, like my Mahapurusha.